# Are the right and left regular representations of any locally compact group always equivalent?

Tags: representation-theory, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

Let $R$ and $L$ be the right and left regular representations of an arbitrary locally compact group G, respectively. We know that $R$ and $L$ are unitary with respect to the right and left Haar measure on $G$, respectively.

My question: Are they equivalent representations for all locally compact groups?

If we take the linear operator $A:L^2(G)\to L^2(G)$ defined by (Af)$(x)=f(x^{-1})$, then we have $AR(t)=L(t)A$ for all $t\in G$. But, to show that the unitarity of $A$, for any $f,h\in L^2(G)$ we need to have that 
\begin{align}
\int_G f(x^{-1})\overline{h(x^{-1})}dx=\int_Gf(x)\overline{h(x)}dx
\end{align}
I am not sure that the above equation is true for all locally compact groups. Also it is possible that there is another intertwining operator $A$ that makes $R$ and $L$ equivalent. Thanks.

Comment: If the group is not unimodular, then the right and left Haar measures may be different and those integrals can be different, I think.

Comment: If $\mu$ is the left-Haar measure, that is $\forall g \in G,\mu(S) = \mu(gS)$ then $$\int_G f(x^{-1})\overline{h(x^{-1})}d\mu(x) = \int_G f(y)\overline{h(y)}d\mu(y^{-1})=\int_G f(y)\overline{h(y)}d\nu(y)$$
 where $\nu(S) = \mu(S^{-1})$ is the right-Haar measure, that is $\forall g \in ,\nu(S) = \nu(Sg)$.

So $\forall f,h \in L^2(G), \qquad \int_G f(x^{-1})\overline{h(x^{-1})}d\mu(x)=\int_G f(x)\overline{h(x)}d\mu(x)$
really means that $\mu = \nu$ ie. $G$ is [unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#The_modular_function)